# Java Compilation error Not able to configure JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, jenkins, javac

When i am running Jenkins which checks out code from a repository and perform `mvn package` or some command. I get this error:

> Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
>   Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
>   In most cases you can change the location of your Java installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

```
My JAVA_HOME points at jdk location only.Still it looks at
```

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/tools.jar
for the compiler.Why is that???

It seems the problem is with the code ..It points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/ for the tools.jar,whereas it needs to look into the /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/lib/ where the jar is present.I tried copying the jar to jre /lib/ but to no avail.Any solutions for this...
Thanks for d answers anyway..

Comment: have you tried setting your JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: try 'which java' command and then 'java -version' then see where you have installed jdk or confirm that either you have jdk or only JRE

Comment: My JDK points at /jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need jdk (java development kit) to compile java programs. jre only use to run compiled java programs. in your case its point to a jre and thats why you are getting this.
you can download the jdk and install.

you can download jdk rpm from here

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u9-downloads-1859576.html
```

use this to choose java alternative if you have already installed.

```
  /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

Comment: use this and check what are the versions you have installed, /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java  and if jdks available you can choose your version here.

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java This is what i am using...But the error says it does not contain a tools.jar

Comment: it seems still you are pointing to jre. I think its better you install the new version of jdk rather using openjdk.

Comment: Hey thanks man...it seems the problem is with the code ..It points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre/../lib/ for the tools.jar,whereas it needs to look into the /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/lib/ where the jar is present.I tried copying the jar to jre /lib/ but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the installed JRE. Keep only one JAVA defined by JAVA_HOME and define your lib and classpath with respect to JAVA_HOME.